# Конверт с ogg в wav Python

Tags: python

Нужно конвертировать с ogg в wav. Как я могу сделать через python.

```
import soundfile as sf  # pip install pysoundfile

data, samplerate = sf.read('existing_file.ogg')
sf.write('new_file.wav', data, samplerate)
```

код выше почему то не работает. Нужно конвертировать голосовое сообщение с тг

Comment: Какая ошибка???

Comment: RuntimeError: Error opening 'audio_2020-10-15_21-35-23.ogg': File contains data in an unimplemented format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852175/how-to-convert-telegram-voice-in-a-wave-file-in-python